# MSForms (Preview) doesnt save my newly created Form

Tags: office-365

[image]I am not sure if this is the right Group to be asking this question, if not please redirect me to the right support Group.

I was playing around with MS Forms within O365 and I created my Questionnaire but every time I try to save it throws an error, is it because its in Preview but I also have noticed some users can build there forms and some cant . Any Idea?

I have tried IE and Chrome( attached Screenshots)

[image]

Comment: I personally haven't used MS Forms, but I have noticed with MS Flow, I have to use Chrome for certain things. Try it in another browser and see if that helps.

Comment: @alexander7567 You are right for flow it works well with Chrome, but MSForms it doesn't work on IE or Chrome either

Comment: Sign-out, delete the cookies and try and if this doesn't work report to MS it must be a bug.  I have been using MS Form without any issues.

Comment: I have worked with MSForms and i haven't faced any issues yet it should work fine. I just tried again and it works for me